# Second monitor not shown up in Screen Display in Ubuntu 20.04 with RTX 3090

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

My second monitor is not showing up in the display settings using an RTX 3090 nVidia GPU, see the first screenshot, I am using Ubuntu 20.04. [image]

I have tried using all of the drivers shown in the screenshot below,

[image]

```
Running xrandr I see:
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440    143.86*+ 119.88    99.90    59.95  
   2560x1080     59.94  
   1920x1080    120.00   119.88   100.00   100.00    60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1440x480      59.94  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Running dmseg piping to a reg expression check for nvidia I get:
dmesg | grep nvidia

```
[    7.515909] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    7.515915] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    7.558852] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 508
[    7.559561] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    7.617777] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  510.47.03  Mon Jan 24 22:51:43 UTC 2022
[    7.632317] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[    8.903911] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[    9.087932] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
[    9.110820] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 506.
[    9.419891] audit: type=1400 audit(1646695235.248:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=1007 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.419894] audit: type=1400 audit(1646695235.248:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=1007 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  746.910272] [drm:nv_drm_connector_get_modes [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to get mode at modeIndex 1 of NvKmsKapiDisplay 0x00000100
[  747.758802] [drm:nv_drm_connector_get_modes [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to get mode at modeIndex 12 of NvKmsKapiDisplay 0x00000200
```

The second monitor is connected by display port and has 4K resolution. Any insights on what to try next much appreciated, I'd be happy to give more information.

Comment: Does it work if you boot with this monitor as the single one connected?.
Can you connect it via HDMI?.
May be the cable as well.

Comment: @CarlesMateo I will check that later tonight, dual monitor works fine in Windows with my dual boot tho.

Comment: Your driver screenshot suggests rebooting. Did you try that?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: No I did not unfortunately.

Comment: @MartinVrkljan actually i reinstalled ubuntu 22.04 and it worked lol, I know this is not a real fix for people who don't want to change OS versions, but it did eventually work.

Comment: @IntegrateThis I'm actually having the same issue on 22.04 and can't seem to fix it :) Oh, well, the quest continues. Thanks for the info.